# Error message with unknown character in UTF8

Tags: input-encodings

I have a problem regarding my `.bib` file and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

After adding the literatur file `\printbibliography` to the main document I get this error message:

[image]

I tried to plot a diagramm with `pgfplots` and afterwards the message the error message came up. Before everything was fine. Could you please help me?

Comment: Add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0080}{HERE-HERE-HERE}` to your document preambel to find out where the problematic input is.

Comment: Unfortunately the error message remains the same.

Comment: @PeterMat -- The suggestion to add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to your input won't change the error message, but it should be very easy to spot the result in the document output, so that you can see where it is occurring.  Then you can change it to something that *does* work.